# Get selection indices while skipping over children tags

Tags: javascript, html

What would be the most efficient native JavaScript way to get the start and end indices of the adjective 'wrapped' in relation to the div tag but skipping over the span tag inside div when I select this word?

```
<div class="sent">This is a <span class="noun">sentence</span> <span class="verb">wrapped</span> in a div tag</div>
```

Right now the start index I get is 0 and the end index 7.
What I want to achieve is to have the start index as 19 and the end index as 26.

The approach I am using is suggested in a similar question:

```
divTag.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e)
{
        var txt = this.innerText;
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var start = selection.anchorOffset;
        var end = selection.focusOffset;
        console.log(start, end)
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code approach? Are you getting it from a string?

Comment: I added the code and updated the html to reflect better the case.

Comment: `selection.anchorOffset` is the node in which the user began selecting the text - so you can not just change that willy-nilly. But you could perhaps create a new range from that node, to the start of the div, then add that to your existing selection & merge them ... something like that. You will have to look into the possibilities the Selection API provides a bit more.